# asp.net - Get data from external application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to know how to link my web application with an external application.

The external application would call my application with a link.

Ex, ../../report/3

here 3 is the id for some data. Now I would gather the data from their database and process it.

Please tell me how to achieve this. What would be the best approach?

I am not started yet. Looking for an idea to start.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about RESTfull services and JSON.

Alternatively you can return a JSON (or XML) according to a query string sent from a client.

If you want some security read about WCF and for older .net you can check out the older Web Services of asp.net

Good luck